# Como quebrar linha após uma linha especifica? PYTHON

Tags: python, string

Minha primeira pergunta aqui galera,

Preciso adicionar uma quebra de linha antes dele escrever o for1 novamente, como faço isso nesse código?

E também gostaria que o for7 fosse o ultimo a ser printado, como no arquivo original ele vem por segundo ele é printado em baixo de for1, e não por ultimo.

````
in_file = "nomes2.txt"
out_file = "remetentes.txt"


for1 = "nome"
for2 = "endereco"
for3 = "numero"
for4 = "bairro"
for5 = "cidade"
for6 = "cep"
for7 = "cpf"



with open(out_file, "w") as out_f:
    with open(in_file, "r") as in_f:
        for line in in_f:
            if for1 in line or for2 in line or for3 in line or for4 in line or for5 in line or for6  in line or for7 in line:
                print(line)
                out_f.write(line.replace('"', '').replace('nome:', '').replace(',',''))
```
````

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).  Faça o nosso [tour]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Acredito que se voce adicionar um `print("\n")`, seja o suficiente embaixo do `out_file`

Comment: isso adiciona uma quebra de linha a cada linha, e preciso que a quebra de linha seja feita apenas a cada nova leitura das variaveis, ou seja: for1, for2, for3, for4 , for5, for6, for7 **ai a quebra de linha** e ai sim novamente essa sequencia

Comment: desculpa, me equivoquei, se voce fizer um if dentro do `if line` falando que quando o for1 in line, você printa o print("\n")

Comment: Muito obrigado irmao, consegui adiconando um if na linha, ai no print ele criou a quebra, sua resposta clareou legal aqui!